# Creating a "developer screen" for game development in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently developing a game on iPhone using the Cocos2D API. It's going well. One issue I'm having though is that I have to recompile each time I want to change my variables. This is very tedious, especially now that I am tweaking gameplay.

Is there any implementation for a sort of developer console screen? What I mean is: I want to have a type of game screen that I load, that contains a list of variables that I register to the game screen(with scroller). And I want to be able to modify these variables on the spot.

I remember there being a presentation on a WWDC event in which they showed such a screen on an ipad. The developer would just press a button and the gamescreen would change to a developer console like screen. I know this presentation had nothing to do with Cocos2D, but still, if this already exists in some shape or form, I would love to re-use this code instead of writing it on my own.

Though if I had to write it on my own, I wouldn't really know where to start. So any help there would be appreciated as well.

Thx!

Comment: Neat idea.  I've always just left an extra menu item (or co-opted the about screen) to test stuff out on.  But I never thought about a place to enter "cheats" to try out simple variable changes on the fly without a rebuild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was (I believe) Graeme Devine at Apple's WWDC last year who had some suggestions on how to implement such a developer console (check the video on iTunes University). An example called **Game Console** is included with the [example code of WWDC 2010 (232 MB)](http://bit.ly/cEf0rM). I've also [added a link (57 kb)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/GameConsole.zip) to *GameConsole.zip* from DropBox, for convenience.

Comment: +1 Thank you my good sir. This is what I was looking for. I'll have to see if I can this integrated into Cocos2D somehow. I'll let you know how it goes. I'm gonna leave this question open just a bit longer, but if no one else has a better response, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a seriously backdated reply but we implemented a developer console for [Mega Run](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mega-run-redfords-adventure/id521906541?mt=8) to test out various stages and modify player properties at run time.  Implementation was to tap in the top left corner of the screen at any point in the game to bring up the console.  From there you could modify to your needs.  The skeleton of the implementation was to override EAGLView and handle the touchesBegan touch callback yourself.  Here is the implementation...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  const CGFloat DEV_DASHBOARD_ENABLE_TOUCH_AREA = 20.0f;

  for (UITouch* t in touches)
  {
    CGPoint pt = [t locationInView:self];

        if (pt.x < DEV_DASHBOARD_ENABLE_TOUCH_AREA && pt.y < DEV_DASHBOARD_ENABLE_TOUCH_AREA)
        {
            ToolSelectorContainer* editorViewController = [[ToolSelectorContainer alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToolSelectorContainer" bundle:nil]; 

            if (editorViewController != nil)
            {
                CCScene* g = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene;

                // Pause the game if we're in it playing
                //
                if ([g isKindOfClass:[Game class]])
                    [((Game *)g) menuPause];

                [[GSGCocos2d sharedInstance].navigationController pushViewController:editorViewController animated:YES];
                [editorViewController release];

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    #endif

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

ifdef is used to not compile this code for production builds.